# Запись массива в текстовой файл

Tags: c#

Есть массив с интервалами работы таймеров. Каждый таймер должен записать эти интервалы в текстовый файл.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] timerDelays = { 10000, 15000, 10000 };

    foreach (int d in timerDelays)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(d);
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    Console.Read();
}

private static void OnTimeout(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int[] timerDelays = { 10000, 15000, 10000 };

    StreamWriter strwrt = new StreamWriter("C:\\пример.txt", true);
    strwrt.WriteLine(timerDelays);

    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER что бы выйти из программы");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Вот мой код. Подскажите или приведите другой пример, пожалуйста. У меня ошибка при записи в файл.

Comment: Добавьте условия вашей задачи. Что вам нужно сделать и где ошибка

Comment: Есть массив таймера, который таймер работает  каждые 1 сек, 1,5 сек и 1 сек . И записывает эти числа в текстовой файл

Comment: @МаксимКутовой    
          
                File.WriteAllLines(path, timerDelays);// тут ошибка

Comment: Нужно решить **одну проблему** - Одновременный доступ к файлу из разных таймеров. У тебя 3 таймера, которые пытаются писать в один и тот же файл. Копай сюда - [Асинхронный файловый вывод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @МаксимКутовой хотя бы покажите ,используя мой пример запись массива в файл, пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //  миллисекунда - это 1/1000 секунды
        int[] timerDelays = { 1000, 1500, 1000 };

        foreach (int d in timerDelays)
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(d);
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        // ожидание в Main, а не в обработчике таймера - таймеры будут работать в фоне
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER что бы выйти из программы");
        Console.Read();
    }

    // общий для всех потоков/таймеров объект
    private static object fileLock = new object();

    private static void OnTimeout(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] timerDelays = { 10000, 15000, 10000 };

        // блокировка на время записи
        lock (fileLock)
        {
            // запись массива как трех строк, в новый файл или в конец существующего
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\temp\пример.txt", timerDelays.Select(t => t.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В задаче две трудности:

**1. Запись массива в файл** 
[MSDN: File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3det53xh(v=vs.110).aspx)

File.WriteAllLines - Создает новый файл, записывает указанный массив строк в этот файл, используя заданную кодировку, затем закрывает файл.

*На всякий случай чтение из файла:* [MSDN: File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) 
File.ReadAllLines - Открывает текстовый файл, считывает все строки файла в массив строк и затем закрывает файл.

```
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            int[] timerDelays = { 10000, 15000, 10000 };
            string[] str = timerDelays.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();           

            string path = @"c:\temp\пример.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))            
              File.WriteAllLines(path, str);            
            else            
              File.AppendAllLines(path, str);

        }
```

**2. Одновременный доступ к файлу из разных таймеров**

один из вариантов решения. У `FileStream` есть 4-ый флаг в конструкторе `FileShare.None`, который отклоняет использование файла если он занят. Прокрутим его в `while (true)`, пока не появится доступ.

```
    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] timerDelays = { 10000, 15000, 10000 };
        FileStream fs = null;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\пример.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }   

        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {                                 
            foreach (int t in timerDelays)
            {
                sr.WriteLine(t);
                Console.WriteLine(t);
            }                
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
        }
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();           
    }
```

Comment: можете в моем примере показать. У  меня ошибку выдает просто

Comment: Я знаю что тут две трудности, и прошу вам показать пример кода запись в файл, а с таймером как нибудь сам попробую. Очень прошу)

Comment: пример можете? Нет?

Comment: @propro17: Ну откройте же документацию, там всё расписано.